# ERROR [ERROR] 20:56.724 AWSPinpointProvider - updateEndpoint failed [TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined]

Tags: ios, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I am new to Amplify, but have successfully created this set up via the CLI for ReactNative:

```
│ Category      │ Resource name  │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │

│ Auth          │ userPoolGroups │ No Change │ awscloudformation │

│ Auth          │ Rent           │ No Change │ awscloudformation │

│ Analytics     │ RentAppIOS     │ No Change │ awscloudformation │

│ Notifications │ RentAppIOS     │ No Change │                   │
```

Right now I am trying to get push notifications to work for IOS using PinPoint. All the permissions look to be OK but I am running into the an error when trying to run updateEndpoint on Analytics which is supposed to create a new endpoint in PinPoint. This is the error:

```
AWSPinpointProvider - updateEndpoint failed [TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined]
```

This is the function which is called after user has logged in and is causing the error:

```
const registerForPushNotifications = async () => {
    const { attributes: {sub} } = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
    if (sub) {
      DeviceInfo.getDeviceToken().then((deviceToken) => {
          Analytics.updateEndpoint({
              address: deviceToken,
              optOut: "NONE",
              userId: sub,
              channelType: "APNS",
        }).then(() => {
           console.log("Endpoint created");
        }).catch((error) => {
           console.log('Error updating endpoint', error);
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

The variables sub and deviceToken have values as expected. Here is the config setup when the app is initiated:

```
Amplify.configure({
  ...awsconfig,
  Analytics: {
    disabled: false,
  },
  Predictions: {
    provider: AmazonAIPredictionsProvider,
    region: awsconfig.aws_mobile_analytics_app_region,
  },
});

Analytics.configure({
  ...awsconfig,
  AWSPinpoint: {
    region: awsconfig.aws_mobile_analytics_app_region,
  },
});
PushNotification.configure({
  ...awsconfig,
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
    Alert.alert(
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      [{ text: 'OK' }],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
    notification.finish("backgroundFetchResultNewData");
  },
  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },
  popInitialNotification: true,
  requestPermissions: true,
});
```

Here is the aws-exports.js file example which is being imported as awsconfig:

```
const awsmobile = {
    aws_project_region: "eu-west-2",
    aws_cognito_identity_pool_id: "eu-west-2:xxxxxxxx-c514-4431-91c0-xxxxxxxx",
    aws_cognito_region: "eu-west-2",
    aws_user_pools_id: "eu-west-2_xxxxxxxx",
    aws_user_pools_web_client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2m5pmf",

    aws_pinpoint_id: "b6846xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    aws_mobile_analytics_app_id: "xxxxxxxxxxete",
    aws_mobile_analytics_app_region: "eu-west-2", 
    aws_mobile_analytics_app_title: "Rent", 
    aws_mobile_analytics_auto_session_record: true,
    aws_mobile_analytics_disabled: false
};

export default awsmobile;
```

I really hope someone can see what is wrong, I've spent days looking over this and available documentation online is not highlighting anything. I appreciate any feedback :)